# Is it possible to obtain the following inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables such that $E\|X\|^{2n}\leq c_1^n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $E\|Y\|^{2n}\leq c_2^n,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Clearly, we have then 
$$E\|X+Y\|^2 \leq 2E\|X\|^2 + 2E\|Y\|^2 \leq 2c_1+2c_2$$

Can we say that $$\sqrt[4]{E\|X+Y\|^8} \leq ac_1 + bc_2$$ for some constants $a,b$? Is there some inequality which allows me to write this?

If I do the brute-force approach I get

$$\sqrt[4]{E\|X+Y\|^8} \leq \sqrt[4]{E\left[\left(2\|X\|^2 + 2\|Y\|^2\right)^4\right]} = 2\sqrt[4]{c_1^4 + 4c_1^3c_2 + 6c_1^2c_2^2 + 4c_1c_2^3 + c_2^4}$$

which does not lead to what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you call the brute force approach yields the upper bound $$2\sqrt[4]{c_1^4 + 4c_1^3c_2 + 6c_1^2c_2^2 + 4c_1c_2^3 + c_2^4}\leqslant2\sqrt[4]{16\max(c_1,c_2)^4}=4\max(c_1,c_2)\leqslant4c_1+4c_2.$$